# Evaluating consecutive dates on a given condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a query that very simply looks like this:

```
SELECT
event_date,
client_id,
error_id
FROM
table.name
```

That isn't the *actual* query, but for the sake of simplicity and having something reproducible, it gives us what we need. This produces an output like this:

```
event_date   client_id   error_id
2018-09-01   12345       232 send failure
2018-09-02   12345       232 send failure
2018-09-03   12345       232 send failure
2018-09-05   12345       232 send failure
2018-09-01   12345       508 server failure
2018-09-02   12345       615 script break
2018-09-01   67890       232 send failure
2018-09-02   67890       232 send failure
2018-09-03   67890       404 load failure
2018-09-01   67890       508 server failure
2018-09-02   67890       615 script break
```

What I'm looking to do is create another column that will "flag" if a client ID is seeing this error on consecutive days. So let's say the first time Client ID #12345 is seeing `232 send failure` is `2018-09-01`. On `2018-09-02` (or any subsequent consecutive date that this error appears, it would be flagged. So that error on `2018-09-05`, despite being the same error for the same Client ID, would not be flagged because it wasn't there on `2018-09-04`. So my ideal output would look like this:

```
event_date   client_id   error_id            flag
2018-09-01   12345       232 send failure    No
2018-09-02   12345       232 send failure    Yes
2018-09-03   12345       232 send failure    Yes
2018-09-05   12345       232 send failure    No
2018-09-01   12345       508 server failure  No
2018-09-02   12345       615 script break    No
2018-09-01   67890       232 send failure    No
2018-09-02   67890       232 send failure    Yes
2018-09-03   67890       404 load failure.   No
2018-09-01   67890       508 server failure  No
2018-09-02   67890       615 script break    Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you would have to self-join this table/result-set to its own date + 1 day with a left join (all other columns matching).

You could then use a case statement to derive the yes/no flag based on whether the join matched anything (checking for any column should be enough here).

```
SELECT event_date, client_id, error_id,
       case when b.event_date is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as flag
FROM table.name a
left join table.name b
on dateadd(day,1,a.event_date) = b.event_date and
   a.client_id = b.client_id and
   a.error_id = b.error_id
```

The left-join will include everything in your table and give you columns for any date + 1 (or null if there isn't one).

I'm not a red-shift user, but it looks like the date-add function above should be fine based on this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `lag()` and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(error_id) over (partition by client_id order by date) = error_id and
                  lag(date) over (partition by client_id order by date) = dateadd(day, -1, date)
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as flag_consecutive_dates
from t;
```